# Can't find any java examples of using the androidx navigation architecture for single activity using bottom navigation

Tags: java, navigation, androidx

I'm unable to find any examples using java, all the codelabs given by google seem to be in kotlin and ideally i don't want to learn that language.

Is there any simple example of using 1 activity, 2/3 fragments all linked in by the bottom navigation bar that I can browse for?

I've looked at all the documentation provided by google and unable to make any sense of it.

All I do know is that i am expected to use

```
 NavHostFragment.findNavController(Fragment)
    Navigation.findNavController(Activity, @IdRes int viewId)
    Navigation.findNavController(View)
```

And that in java i should be using

```
 Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener()
```

I am hoping i am not too far off with this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

NavController navController;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);

    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView,navController);
}
```

}

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually found the answer, for anyone else who is facing similar newbie issues:

/res/layout/activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java under onCreate

```
  BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView,navController);
```

Under /res/navigation/nav_graph.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/mapFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
        android:name="com.company.pinpoint.MapFragment"
        android:label="fragment_map"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_map">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mapFragment_to_newsFeedFragment"
            app:destination="@id/newsFeedFragment" />
        <!--app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"-->
        <!--app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"-->
        <!--app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"-->
        <!--app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right" />-->
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/newsFeedFragment"
        android:name="com.company.pinpoint.NewsFeedFragment"
        android:label="fragment_news_feed"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_news_feed" />
</navigation>
```